# Heroku file changing

Tags: python, heroku

I have a discord bot made with python and recently I started streaming it to heroku. To that bot I have a database and it seems like heroku resets the file of the database with every deployment and I just want to know is there something I have to do to allow Heroku change the files on their source (They are on github).

Answer (score 0):

Heroku file system is [ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) so files are temporary and removed at every Dyno restart and application re-deployment.
You need to save any data (which is not temporary) on an external storage like a DB or remote file system.

If you are looking at saving plain files you read this [Files on Heroku](https://medium.com/geekculture/files-on-heroku-cd09509ed285) to see few options.
If you want to update the data on Github you need to do it from your application, basically performing a commit (using PyGithub).